# Regex selecting date delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, date

How to select the delimiters of a date strictly with a regex?

I'm using this: `(\W)(?=(dd|MM|yyyy))`

And I'm taking this example:  `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

But when I had any spaces in front of a **dd** for example I'm getting that, how can I scape this, in other words, how can I create an exception in`\W` to not catch spaces?

Comment: I would not recommend parsing dates with regexp. There are lots of tricky cases and its not always straight forward, consider using https://momentjs.com/ for working with dates.

Comment: Use word boundaries `\b`

Comment: @asosnovsky with moment is possible to change the delimiters?

Comment: @AndréVinícius can you provide us with some sample strings and can you present us with sample output of what you expect to get as a result?

Comment: @AndréVinícius with moment you can set any custom format https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: @asosnovsky I have checked before but I cant found nothing about change the delimiters in a "high level" like `.setDateDelimiter(...)`

Comment: @ctwheels I want to "detect", in most common cases, the date delimiters, if you know a better way, I'll be glad if you let me know

Comment: @AndréVinícius as I mentioned in an earlier comment, you can use word boundaries `\b` such that you end up with something like `\bPATTERNHERE\b`, where `PATTERHERE` is your pattern

Comment: Why do you want to "select the delimiters"? If the values are only digits, then `/\D+/` will do, so the delimiters are any non–digit sequence of characters. But usually the delimiter is of zero interest, it's the values you're after so you might want `string.match(/\d+/g)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can filter non-whitespace `\S` instead of a word. Ofcourse this means that spaces can no longer be used as a delimiter.

```
(\S)(?=(dd|MM|yyyy))
```

This works for your example with a space before the date

```
 dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Can I check if there is a string in front of "\S"?